# Find path in a matrix of 0's and 1's

Tags: python, c, algorithm, matrix, depth-first-search

Recently I came across the following interview question?

**Ques:** You are given a 2-D matrix with M rows and N columns.You are initially positioned at (0,0) which is the top-left cell in the array. You are allowed to move either right or downwards. The array is filled with 1’s and 0’s. A 1 indicates that you can move through that cell, a 0 indicates that you cannot move through that cell. Return the number of paths from top-left cell to bottom-right cell.(i.e. (0,0)to(M-1,N-1)). Since answer can be large thus you have to return ans%(10^9+7).

Can anyone tell me how to approach or any algorithm that might help?

**Edit** :

```
I have an approach 
1.Start with the top-left cell,initialize count=0
do 
2.Check if 1 exists in adjacent right or adjacent down cell.
3.Add the tuple (i,j) in the stack and choose the right path.
4.If we reach the bottom right cell , update count and pop from stack and go to that position (i,j).
while(stack is not empty)
5.Print count
```

I was wondering if someone has some other approach?

Comment: This is extremely trivial, there's no backtracking involved at any point. What precisely stumps you?

Comment: I'm looking for different solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can model your problem as a [Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph), and then you are looking for number of paths from vertex `s` to vertex `t`, which is pretty easy to do in DAG using [Dynamic Programming (DP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming).

In here, it will be done with the following pseudo code:

```
D(0,0) = 1 
D(x,y) = 0                      if x < 0
D(x,y) = 0                      if  y < 0
D(x,y) = 0                      if matrix[x][y] = 0
         D(x,y-1) + D(x-1,y)    Otherwise
```

By applying Dynamic Programming approach on the above, you will get a matrix, where `D(x,y)` indicates the number of paths from `(0,0)` to `(x,y)`, and your solution is `D(n,m)`.

Time complexity of this solution is `O(n*m)`

---

Implementing this solution is left for you, since it should be fairly easy after understanding how it is done.

Comment: A Slight edit D(x,y) = 0 if(x<0) similarly D(x,y) = 0 if(y<0). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Guys after all my efforts finally I am submitting my code, This prints the path positions in matrix starting from (0,0).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

rows, cols = 0, 0
def traverse_matrix(A, directions, i, j, visited):
    global rows, cols
    def can_we_proceed(A, row, col, visited, current):
        return (row >=0 and row < rows and col >=0 and col < cols and \
                not visited[row][col] and (current == A[row][col]) and A[row][col] == 1)

    visited[i][j] = True
    for k in range(len(directions)):
        if can_we_proceed(A, i+directions[k][0], j+directions[k][1], visited, A[i][j]):
            print "({0},{1})".format(i+directions[k][0],j+directions[k][1])
            traverse_matrix(A, directions, i+directions[k][0], j+directions[k][1], visited)

def mysolution(a):
    global rows, cols
    rows, cols = len(a) , len(a[0])
    if (rows == 1 or cols == 1):
        return 1
    directions = [[1, 0], [0, -1], [-1, 0], [0, 1]]
    visited = []
    for i in range(rows):
        l = []
    for j in range(cols):
        l.append(False)
    visited.append(l)

    # tup1 = ();
    for i in range(rows):
        for j in range(cols):
            # tup1 = (i,j);
            if not visited[i][j]:
                traverse_matrix(A, directions, i, j, visited)   
                # print "Traversed {0};".format(tup1)
```

Comment: Have written code in Python as I felt more comfortable with it. And this works with time complexity O(M*N)